# SpringBoot 2.7 SecurityfilterChain why ignore UserDetailsService?

Tags: java, spring-boot, basic-authentication

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig {

        @Autowired UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers( "/**" ).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().and().userDetailsService( userDetailsService );
            return http.build();
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    }
```

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger            logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( UserDetailsServiceImpl.class );

    @Autowired private DBService db;
    @Autowired private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        if( username.equals( " " ) || username.isEmpty() ) {
            return null;
        }

        int ret = db.checkUser( username );
        
        if( ret == 0 ) throw new UsernameNotFoundException( "Invalid user" );

        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<>( 2 );
        authList.add( new SimpleGrantedAuthority( "ROLE_USER" ) );

        return new User( username, passwordEncoder.encode( username ), true, true, true, true, authList );
    }
}
```

I am a beginner in springboot.
I'm trying to create an api server with a simple get, post function.

> Hypertext Transfer Protocol
> GET /getcontens/1 HTTP/1.1
> Accept: */*
> Host: localhost:8080
> Cookie: JSESSIONID=12pfvmq3rsac410tojukfkvlip
> Authorization: Basic ODQ1OTY6ODQ1OTY=
> Credentials: id:password

The request uses http basic authentication as above

I disabled csrf to avoid 401 response due to csrf protection during post.

The problem is that if you create a securityFilterChain to disable csrf

The loadUserbyUsername function of UserDetilsService implemented in UserDetailsServiceImpl is not called.

I've been googling for the past week and I've noticed that this is my problem not meeting the right csrf conditions

Currently, csrf is not available

To sum up the situation

1. Disable csrf
2. using loadUserByUsername

I'm asking for advice on the right path to do it

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CustomUserDetailService();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
                .csrf(a -> a.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                        .requestMatchers( "/user")
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/books/**")
                        .authenticated())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

Service layer:

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        user.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Not found: " + username));
        return user.map(MyUserDetails::new).get();
    }

    public String addUser(User user){
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "User saved";
    }
}
```

Repository layer:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

UserDetials:

```
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public MyUserDetails(User user) {
        username = user.getUsername();
        password = user.getPassword();
        active = user.isEnabled();
        authorities = Arrays.stream(user.getRoles().split(","))
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return active;
    }
}
```

User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String roles;
    private boolean enabled;
}
```

Comment: The login feature does not exist in my project.
When I got a request, I was going to check if there was a user on the db and move on.
I know what the example sentence means, but it's not right for me.